# Resolver SwiftUI Causing Crash - What Order Do Things Get Called?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, resolver

I am working on SwiftUI and using Resolver for Dependency Injection. As a backend I am using Firebase. I've created an AuthSession file that handles all of my user authentication stuff. In the project I also have a number of other repositories that populate data throughout the app. In AuthSession I am creating properties for each repository so that I can start and stop Firestore Listeners on login and logout. In a couple of these repositories I want to access AuthSession through @InjectedObject so that when a user logs in I can be notified and can get updates via Combine. My issues is that when I start the app, it crashes with an odd Firebase error.

AuthSession.swift

```
class AuthSession: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var offerRepository: OfferRepository = Resolver.resolve()
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var loggedIn = false
    @Published var currentUserUid = ""
    
    // Combine Cancellable
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    // Intitalizer
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func listen() {
        print("AuthSession - listen called")
        // Monitor Authentication chagnes using Firebase Auth.
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener{ (auth, user) in
            // Check to see if a user is returned from a sign in or sign up event.
            if let user = user {
                // Set loggedIn to true. This will also be set when a new User is created in SignUpView.
                print("User Exists.")
                self.loggedIn = true
                self.currentUserUid = user.uid
                self.currentUser = user
            } else {
                print("Not logged in")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is OfferRepository. When the line below is added it crashes. If the line is removed it does not crash. I'm not sure why. The Combine code is not included.

Line causing the crash.

```
@InjectedObject var authSession: AuthSession
```

OfferRepository.swift

```
class OfferRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @InjectedObject var authSession: AuthSession

    @Published var offers = [Offer]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
        
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        if snapshotListener == nil {
            self.snapshotListener = db.collection(FirestoreCollection.offers).order(by: "created", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No Offers.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self.offers = documents.compactMap { offer in
                        do {
                            return try offer.data(as: Offer.self)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

For reference here is my AppDelegate+Registering file.

```
extension Resolver: ResolverRegistering {
    public static func registerAllServices() {
        register { AuthSession() }.scope(.application)
        register { OfferRepository() as OfferRepository }.scope(.application)
    }
}
```

The app crashed on the line below from the Firestore package.

```
- (NSString *)keyForDatabase:(NSString *)database {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@", self.app.name, database];
}
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d317ff8)

While I can start and stop listeners from login and logout views, I'd prefer to keep this in the AuthSession file. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

`@InjectedObject` is intended to be used to inject `ObservableObject`s into SwiftUI views - see the docs: https://github.com/hmlongco/Resolver#property-wrappers

As you want to reference the `AuthenticationService` inside your repositories (which are `ObservableObject`s, you should use `@Injected` instead.

Here is a snippet from one of my apps:

```swift
public class ArtifactRepository: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Dependencies
  @Injected var db: Firestore
  @Injected var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  
  // MARK: - Publishers
  @Published public var artifacts = [Artifact]()
  
  // MARK: - Private attributes
  private var statusFilter: Status
  private var userId: String = "unknown"
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
  let logger = Logger(subsystem: "dev.peterfriese.App", category: "persistence")
  
  public init(statusFilter: Status = .inbox, liveSync: Bool = true) {
    // filtering
    self.statusFilter = statusFilter
    
    // observe user ID
    authenticationService.$user
      .compactMap { user in
        user?.uid
      }
      .assign(to: \.userId, on: self)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    // if live sync is on, (re)load data when user changes
    if liveSync {
      authenticationService.$user
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] user in
          if self?.listenerRegistration != nil {
            self?.unsubscribe()
            self?.subscribe()
          }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
  }
  
  deinit {
    unsubscribe()
  }
  
  public func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
      listenerRegistration = nil
    }
  }
  
  public func subscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
      
      var query = db.collection("artifacts")
        .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: self.userId)
      
      if (statusFilter != .all) {
        query = query.whereField("status", isEqualTo: statusFilter.rawValue)
      }
      
      listenerRegistration = query.order(by: "dateAdded", descending: true)
        .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            self?.logger.debug("No documents")
            return
          }
          
          self?.logger.debug("Mapping \(documents.count) documents")
          self?.artifacts = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
            try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Artifact.self)
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {
  private let logger = Logger(subsystem: "dev.peterfriese.App", category: "authentication")
  
  @Published public var user: User?
  
  private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
  
  public init() {
    setupKeychainSharing()
    registerStateListener()
  }
  
  public func signIn() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
      Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
    }
  }
  
  public func signOut() {
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    catch {
      print("error when trying to sign out: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
  
  private let accessGroup = "XXXXXXX.dev.peterfriese.App"
  
  private func setupKeychainSharing() {
    do {
      let auth = Auth.auth()
      auth.shareAuthStateAcrossDevices = true
      try auth.useUserAccessGroup(accessGroup)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
      print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
    }
  }
  
  private func registerStateListener() {
    if handle == nil {
      handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        self.user = user
        
        if let user = user {
          if user.isAnonymous {
            self.logger.debug("User signed in anonymously with user ID \(user.uid).")
          }
          else {
            self.logger.debug("User signed in with user ID \(user.uid). Email: \(user.email ?? "(empty)"), display name: [\(user.displayName ?? "(empty)")]")
          }
        }
        else {
          self.logger.debug("User signed out.")
          self.signIn()
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I read this I realized InjectedObject is intended for Views. Thanks for help.

Comment: I thought this was the answer but the crash still happens. This seems very strange. In your example you are not trying to resolve ArtifactRepository in AuthenticationService. I believe this is the issue.

Comment: I just noticed you seem to have a dependency cycle in your code: AuthSession depends on OfferRepository (see the line `var offerRepository: OfferRepository = Resolver.resolve()`), and OfferRepository depends on AuthSession (see line `@InjectedObject var authSession: AuthSession`). I bet if you look at your call stack you will notice you've got a stack overflow. Your AuthSession should never depend on your repos - only the other way round.